# Forge keeps crashing on Minecraft (1.7.10)

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-forge

## Versions

- Minecraft Coder Pack **9.05**
- Forge Mod Loader **7.10.18.1180**
- Minecraft Forge **10.13.0.1180**
- Java **1.6.0_65**

## Mods

- Crossbow Mod 2 **a0.1.6.33**
- Galacticraft Core **2.0.14.1084**
- M-Ore **3.0Pre**
- MusicCraft **2.9.2**
- Scenter **3.1.0**

## Crash Report

```
---- Minecraft Crash Report ----
// Surprise! Haha. Well, this is awkward.

Time: 8/4/14 8:46 PM
Description: Initializing game

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: cpw/mods/fml/common/network/IPacketHandler
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:249)
    at cpw.mods.fml.common.FMLModContainer.constructMod(FMLModContainer.java:420)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.google.common.eventbus.EventSubscriber.handleEvent(EventSubscriber.java:74)
    at com.google.common.eventbus.SynchronizedEventSubscriber.handleEvent(SynchronizedEventSubscriber.java:47)
    at com.google.common.eventbus.EventBus.dispatch(EventBus.java:322)
    at com.google.common.eventbus.EventBus.dispatchQueuedEvents(EventBus.java:304)
    at com.google.common.eventbus.EventBus.post(EventBus.java:275)
    at cpw.mods.fml.common.LoadController.sendEventToModContainer(LoadController.java:208)
    at cpw.mods.fml.common.LoadController.propogateStateMessage(LoadController.java:187)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.google.common.eventbus.EventSubscriber.handleEvent(EventSubscriber.java:74)
    at com.google.common.eventbus.SynchronizedEventSubscriber.handleEvent(SynchronizedEventSubscriber.java:47)
    at com.google.common.eventbus.EventBus.dispatch(EventBus.java:322)
    at com.google.common.eventbus.EventBus.dispatchQueuedEvents(EventBus.java:304)
    at com.google.common.eventbus.EventBus.post(EventBus.java:275)
    at cpw.mods.fml.common.LoadController.distributeStateMessage(LoadController.java:118)
    at cpw.mods.fml.common.Loader.loadMods(Loader.java:492)
    at cpw.mods.fml.client.FMLClientHandler.beginMinecraftLoading(FMLClientHandler.java:204)
    at net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.func_71384_a(Minecraft.java:480)
    at net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.func_99999_d(Minecraft.java:867)
    at net.minecraft.client.main.Main.main(SourceFile:148)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.Launch.launch(Launch.java:134)
    at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.Launch.main(Launch.java:28)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: cpw.mods.fml.common.network.IPacketHandler
    at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.LaunchClassLoader.findClass(LaunchClassLoader.java:188)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    ... 35 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.LaunchClassLoader.findClass(LaunchClassLoader.java:180)
    ... 37 more


A detailed walkthrough of the error, its code path and all known details is as follows:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

-- Head --
Stacktrace:
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:249)
    at cpw.mods.fml.common.FMLModContainer.constructMod(FMLModContainer.java:420)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.google.common.eventbus.EventSubscriber.handleEvent(EventSubscriber.java:74)
    at com.google.common.eventbus.SynchronizedEventSubscriber.handleEvent(SynchronizedEventSubscriber.java:47)
    at com.google.common.eventbus.EventBus.dispatch(EventBus.java:322)
    at com.google.common.eventbus.EventBus.dispatchQueuedEvents(EventBus.java:304)
    at com.google.common.eventbus.EventBus.post(EventBus.java:275)
    at cpw.mods.fml.common.LoadController.sendEventToModContainer(LoadController.java:208)
    at cpw.mods.fml.common.LoadController.propogateStateMessage(LoadController.java:187)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.google.common.eventbus.EventSubscriber.handleEvent(EventSubscriber.java:74)
    at com.google.common.eventbus.SynchronizedEventSubscriber.handleEvent(SynchronizedEventSubscriber.java:47)
    at com.google.common.eventbus.EventBus.dispatch(EventBus.java:322)
    at com.google.common.eventbus.EventBus.dispatchQueuedEvents(EventBus.java:304)
    at com.google.common.eventbus.EventBus.post(EventBus.java:275)
    at cpw.mods.fml.common.LoadController.distributeStateMessage(LoadController.java:118)
    at cpw.mods.fml.common.Loader.loadMods(Loader.java:492)
    at cpw.mods.fml.client.FMLClientHandler.beginMinecraftLoading(FMLClientHandler.java:204)
    at net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.func_71384_a(Minecraft.java:480)

-- Initialization --
Details:
Stacktrace:
    at net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.func_99999_d(Minecraft.java:867)
    at net.minecraft.client.main.Main.main(SourceFile:148)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.Launch.launch(Launch.java:134)
    at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.Launch.main(Launch.java:28)

-- System Details --
Details:
    Minecraft Version: 1.7.10
    Operating System: Mac OS X (x86_64) version 10.9.2
    Java Version: 1.6.0_65, Apple Inc.
    Java VM Version: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (mixed mode), Apple Inc.
    Memory: 56219936 bytes (53 MB) / 257597440 bytes (245 MB) up to 1060372480 bytes (1011 MB)
    JVM Flags: 5 total; -Xmx1G -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+CMSIncrementalMode -XX:-UseAdaptiveSizePolicy -Xmn128M
    AABB Pool Size: 0 (0 bytes; 0 MB) allocated, 0 (0 bytes; 0 MB) used
    IntCache: cache: 0, tcache: 0, allocated: 0, tallocated: 0
    FML: MCP v9.05 FML v7.10.18.1180 Minecraft Forge 10.13.0.1180 8 mods loaded, 8 mods active
    mcp{9.05} [Minecraft Coder Pack] (minecraft.jar) Unloaded->Constructed
    FML{7.10.18.1180} [Forge Mod Loader] (forge-1.7.10-10.13.0.1180.jar) Unloaded->Constructed
    Forge{10.13.0.1180} [Minecraft Forge] (forge-1.7.10-10.13.0.1180.jar) Unloaded->Constructed
    CrossbowMod2{a0.1.6} [Crossbow Mod 2] (Crossbow-Mod-2-1.6.4-a0.1.6.33.jar) Unloaded
    GalacticraftCore{2.0.14} [Galacticraft Core] (Galacticraft-1.6.4-2.0.14.1084.jar) Unloaded
    more{1.0} [more] (M-Ore 1.7.2 3.0Pre.jar) Unloaded
    musiccraft{2.9.2} [MusicCraft] (musiccraft-2.9.2.jar) Unloaded
    Scenter{1.7.2-3.1.0} [Scenter] (scenter-1.7.2-3.1.0.jar) Unloaded
    Launched Version: 1.7.10-Forge10.13.0.1180
    LWJGL: 2.9.1
    OpenGL: Intel HD Graphics 3000 OpenGL Engine GL version 2.1 INTEL-8.24.11, Intel Inc.
    GL Caps: Using GL 1.3 multitexturing.
Using framebuffer objects because ARB_framebuffer_object is supported and separate blending is supported.
Anisotropic filtering is supported and maximum anisotropy is 16.
Shaders are available because OpenGL 2.1 is supported.

    Is Modded: Definitely; Client brand changed to 'fml,forge'
    Type: Client (map_client.txt)
    Resource Packs: [PixelDaydreams.zip]
    Current Language: English (US)
    Profiler Position: N/A (disabled)
    Vec3 Pool Size: 0 (0 bytes; 0 MB) allocated, 0 (0 bytes; 0 MB) used
    Anisotropic Filtering: Off (1)
```

## Specs

- OS: Mac OS X (x86_64) **10.9.2**
- RAM: **1024MB**
- Video: Intel HD Graphics 3000 **OpenGL 2.1**

Comment: which mods and how many?

Comment: I am not sure but I think something is wrong with the mod. Maybe you are using a old version either of the mod or forge. It seems a class is missing... It also could be that one mod is overwriting a other mod...

Comment: My guess would be that *Crossbow Mod 2* and *Galacticraft Core* are incompatible with your current version -- their filenames indicate that they're for `1.6.4`, while you're using `1.7.10`.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is tech support for modded Minecraft. We only provide tech support for vanilla Minecraft.

Answer (score 3):

In the details of your error your mods are listed as

```
CrossbowMod2{a0.1.6} [Crossbow Mod 2] (Crossbow-Mod-2-1.6.4-a0.1.6.33.jar) Unloaded
GalacticraftCore{2.0.14} [Galacticraft Core] (Galacticraft-1.6.4-2.0.14.1084.jar) Unloaded
more{1.0} [more] (M-Ore 1.7.2 3.0Pre.jar) Unloaded
musiccraft{2.9.2} [MusicCraft] (musiccraft-2.9.2.jar) Unloaded
Scenter{1.7.2-3.1.0} [Scenter] (scenter-1.7.2-3.1.0.jar) Unloaded
```

The problem is clearly that you are trying to run mods that are not for 1.7.10 with 1.7.10.

- [CrossbowMod2 a0.1.6](http://micdoodle8.com/mods/crossbowmod2/downloads) is for Minecraft 1.6.4. Unfortunately, there is no version for 1.7.XX, let alone 1.7.10, so you will not be able to use it in 1.7.10 at all.
- [GalactiCraft Core 2.0.14](http://micdoodle8.com/mods/galacticraft/downloads) is for 1.6.4. You can try the beta-version for 1.7.10 instead.
- [M-Ore 3.0Pre](http://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/mapping-and-modding/minecraft-mods/1286912-m-ore-mod-4-0) is for 1.7.2. There's a version for 1.7.10 available though.
- Musicraft I have no idea which version your mod-version (2.9.2) is for, but you can get [Version 2.9.4](http://www.planetminecraft.com/mod/musiccraft-add-playable-instruments-to-minecraft/) for use with MC 1.7.10
- [Scenter 3.1.0](http://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/mapping-and-modding/minecraft-mods/1287428-1-7-10-forge-sp-mp-scenter-3-2-0-scent-out-hidden) is for 1.7.2. You can get Version 3.2.0 for use with MC 1.7.10

Remove the mods from the folder, download the correct versions (where possible) and try again (without CrossbowMod2)